# Python -- pygame error 'str object has not attribute 'render'

Tags: python, pygame

I am building a hangman game in python, and for some reason, when trying to display a game over message in the function def drawGameOver, i get the following error: "'str' object has no attribute 'render'". What is wrong with the code i have? How would i go about displaying "Game Over" towards the bottom middle of the screen? I've given what i believe to be the only relevant code. The error is for the line directly below the "#display game over message" comment. Thanks!

```
# this function draws the game over screen    
def drawGameOver(screen, fontObj, gameOverMsg, secretWord):
# draw a filled rectangle
pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,255),(0,375,640,100))
# draw a border rectangle
# display the game over message
overMsg = fontObj.render(gameOverMsg, True, (255,255,255),(0,0,0))
overRect = overMsg.get_rect()
screen.blit(overMsg,overRect)
# display the secret word
print("")

def main():
# initialize pygame
pygame.init()
# create the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,440))
# fill the screen w/ white
screen.fill((255,255,255))

fontObj = pygame.font.SysFont('bookantiqua', 28, True, False)
# here is the magic: making the text input
# create an input with a max length of 45,
# and a red color and a prompt saying 'type here: '
txtbx = eztext.Input(x=0, y=350, color=(0,0,0), prompt='You entered: ')

# get the secret word
secretWord = getRandomWord(words)
#variables to hold the incorrect and correct letters
missedLetters = ""
correctLetters = ""
#gameoverMsg is initialized to be empty
gameOverMsg = "Game Over"
#game is not over yet
gameIsDone = False
```

Comment: Add the line number that you are getting the error on.

Comment: The error pretty much means what it says; somewhere you are not actually passing the `pygame.Surface` that `Font.render()` returns, you're just passing a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `fontObj` you are passing in is a string instead of a font object. That is the only thing that you are trying to render.

Comment: Could you be more specific? fontObj is defined to be a font, and the first parameter of render() is a string, which it is supposed to be.

Comment: You are defining fontObj here correctly
    fontObj = pygame.font.SysFont('bookantiqua', 28, True, False)
I can only presume that somewhere after this, or in the call to drawGameOver that fontObj is redefined as a string.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that i needed to redefine fontObj in this specific function.